# Is there a way to convert jupyter notebook to pdf using NBCONVERT in windows prompt?

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I'm trying to convert a jupyter notebook file (.ipynb) to PDF with this command line:

`jupyter nbconvert --to pdf {my file}.ipynb`

But I get this:

> [NbConvertApp] WARNING | Config option `template_path` not recognized by `PDFExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?

At first, it seems it worked, because the CMD starts running anyway.

But then, I get:

> nbconvert.exporters.pdf.LatexFailed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
> Failed to run "xelatex notebook.tex -quiet" command:
> C:\Users\jfcar\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xete
> x.def:80: Argument of
> C:\Users\jfcar\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xete
> x.def:80: Paragraph ended before
> C:\Users\jfcar\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xete
> x.def:80: Missing number, treated as zero
> C:\Users\jfcar\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xete
> x.def:80: Missing = inserted for
> C:\Users\jfcar\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xete
> x.def:80: Missing number, treated as zero
> C:\Users\jfcar\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xete
> x.def:80:
> C:\Users\jfcar\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xete
> x.def:80: You can't use `

So, I already installed Miktex and Pandoc, but it still doesn't work.

The reason i want to convert it by command line (and not directly in jupyter) is because i want my notebook PDF without the code and it seems that the only way of doing this is with:

`jupyter nbconvert --to pdf {my file}.ipynb --no input`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is an option to export to PDF with Puppeteer support (IMO easier installation). Please just use the `webpdf`, example command: `jupyter notebook --to webpdf --no-input notebook.ipynb`. I wrote [article about different ways to export notebook to PDF](https://mljar.com/blog/jupyter-notebook-pdf/). The alternative might be to use [`Mercury`](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) for a notebook to PDF conversion. As a side effect you will be able to parametrize notebook with interactive widgets :)

Answer (score 0):

Primarily, the nbconvert tool allows you to convert a Jupyter .ipynb notebook document file into another static format including HTML, LaTeX, PDF, Markdown, reStructuredText, and more. nbconvert can also add productivity to your workflow when used to execute notebooks programmatically.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32241493)

Answer (score -2):

You can use 'notebook-as-pdf' python package to do this.

**pip install -U notebook-as-pdf**

You need an additional setup for Chromium. It is used to perform the HTML to PDF conversion. Just run the following code in your code prompt.

**pyppeteer-install**

Just like that, you have already finished your preparation. Now, open the notebook you intend to convert into the PDF. In your notebook, click the file menu bar then select 'Download as' then select the PDF via HTML to transform the notebook.

If you prefer to use command prompt to convert the notebook, you could do it with the following code.

**jupyter-nbconvert --to PDFviaHTML example.ipynb**

See more details [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyter-notebook-to-pdf-in-a-few-lines-3c48d68a7a63).

Regards

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)